# How to get the Source name of a particular contact from Address book?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

My Address book app backs-up all the contacts from iPhone native address book. I want my address book app to sort the contacts by its source name.
I tried kABSourceNameProperty & kABSourceTypeProperty, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From a `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering` you can get individual `ABRecordRef`. Then you can access the `kABPersonFirstName` and `kABPersonLastNameProperty`